# I am returning value of a function and displaying it in angularJS form it is displaying -"[object Object]" instead of actual value.?.?

Tags: angularjs

when i am doing this in my code it is displaying [object Object][object Object], and country and city values are coming from database.
how to display actual values of country and city.

Comment: How do you print it? Using `{{ }}` ?

Comment: please [read about javascript/angularjs first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881054/how-to-learn-angularjs)

Comment: Please share your Html and controller code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you need to display the item, can you explain the properties of the object you return from server side
for ex: assuming your object is something like this

`{ "country: : "United States", "city": "New York"}`

and if your angular controller assign it as below

`$scope.location = locationObj`

then in the template you can specify

`<div>{{location.city}}</div>
<div>{{location.country}}</div>`

If you can explain little bit more up to what level you have done the coding we can answer bit more accurate.

Comment: i have used the same code in  project but it is showing [object Object].. is that because i have declared Jason array for country..?@Tekz

Comment: so your country is an array?, as others mentioned, it is better if you can post your code here to look at, at least the parts in question